# Hide GWT output folders in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt

How can I hide the output folders (/war/com.projname.EntryPoint/) in the /war/ folder in Eclipse's Package Explorer?

I've tried setting the folders to 'Derived' but it doesn't chage a thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the "Customize view" menu doesn't allow adding new filters. If the filter you need is not in the list, there is something else you can do:

- Right-click on the project in the Project Explorer view, choose "Properties"
- Expand "Resource", choose "Resource Filters"
- Click "Add", and choose the appropriate rule

If you want to hide files from a subset of your project files, you can right-click any directory of your project and choose properties for only that directory and its subdirectories.

That worked on Eclipse Helios Service Release 2.

Comment: Yep, it's been added now, which is quite neat.

Comment: Unfortunately, using Eclipse Juno, adding a rule to force the "bin" directory to be visible does not work.

Answer (score 2):

In the 'Project Explorer', if you click on the triangle on the upper right hand side and select 'Customize View', you should be able to set a filter on 'Java Output Folders' (ie the checkbox for this field should be selected).

Comment: The question is: ... in Eclipse's Package Explorer

Comment: It is pretty much the same for the Package Explorer and Project Explorer -- I happened to have the Project Explorer open at the time.

Comment: Eclipse Juno does not display this "Java Output Folders" option, at least this is the case with a Maven project.  I define output through Maven and its really annoying that Eclipse hides this dir from me.

Answer (score -1):

In the **Package Explorer**, click the triangle button on the toolbar. Select **Filters...** and add add appropriate exclusion rule for the output directory.